# Is it possible to retain form radio selections using the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, webforms

The user can select a radio button and depending on which radio button is selected, an input field can show asking for additional information.  The user submits the form; then say they need to go back and make a change to the form.  When they go back, the input field is no longer showing but the correct radio button is selected.

The answer only needs to work in IE8+.
Using jQuery as part of the solution is also an option.

--==UPDATED 7/31/2012 using the jQuery plugin simsalabim ==--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!---<script src="sisyphus.min.js"></script>--->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus/master/sisyphus.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').sisyphus();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    function ToggleColorOptions(el) {
    if (el == 'Std')
            {
        $('#Option1').show();
        $('#Option2').hide();
    }
        else if (el == 'Non')
            {
                $('#Option1').hide();
                $('#Option2').show();
            }
        }
</script>

<form id="form1" action="myTesta.cfm" method="post">
<input name="StdRNonStdOption" type="radio" id="StdRNonStdOption_std" onclick="ToggleColorOptions('Std');" value="Std" />
Standard <br />
<input name="StdRNonStdOption" type="radio" id="StdRNonStdOption_non" onclick="ToggleColorOptions('Non');" value="Non" />
Non-Standard <br />

<div id="Option1" style="display:none;">
    <select name="ThisColor" >
        <option></option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Green</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="Option2" style="display:none;">
    <input name="ThisColor" type="text" size="20" maxlength="51" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like Sisyphus, gmail-like client side localStorage plugin. Probably your best option...

http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/

Comment: This worked great for retaining the values selected but it doesn't remember which elements should be hidden or displayed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in JQuery:

Make an input type button

Put your expanded onclick options in a div with a class name someexpandedoptions

On the click event toggle visibility

```
$('.someexpandedoptions').css('display','inline');

$('.someexpandedoptions').css('display','none');
```

It's as easy as that.

Just make sure to properly initialize your buttons.

Comment: your solution seems more for toggling the display of the input box... am I mistaken?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on how browsers remember the form before you submitted the form

Some browsers do and some do not ... and there is no easy way to make them remember after the form submission ... 

e.g. firefox does a good job of remembering ... but IE does not ... look into history API, client side local storage for answers